# UIBarButtonItem ignores title attributes when in UIToolBar in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I started a new master detail project in Xcode and I added a single `UIBarButtonItem` to the `UIToolBar`. In `viewDidLoad` I try and set some appearance attributes on the button.

```
self.button.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Normal)
self.button.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor()], forState: .Disabled)
```

The problem is that the attributes for the `.Disabled` state are never used, even when I set `self.button.enabled = false`. The button always uses the red color from the `.Normal` state.

What's stranger is that if I put the exact same button in the `navigationBar` then the disabled state works fine. What gives?

Comment: Try `self.button.enabled = NO;`

Comment: @Mikael that's not valid in Swift. I'm doing the equivalent `self.button.enabled = false`.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? I'm seeing this on ios 9.3. Even when using UIAppearance methods also.